# Why does my Flask website fail to export data to an Excel file, despite no errors?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I have developed a simple python Flask website where my goal is users can fill a form and then be able to view their previous inputs in a html table and be able to choose and export some rows of the table in a excel file. Although the site is working fine in all other aspects (data are correctly being stored in the database, they also display fine in a table format etc), the export to an excel file can't seem to work...

The part of my html code for the page that tries to export the html table to an excel is the following :

```html
      <button id="exportButton" class="btn btn-primary">Export to Excel</button>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#projectTable').DataTable();

        $('#exportButton').click(function () {
          var selectedRows = [];
          $('.row-checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            var rowData = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').map(function () {
              return $(this).text();
            }).get();
            selectedRows.push(rowData);
          });

          // Send selectedRows to the server for export
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/export',
            data: JSON.stringify(selectedRows),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (response) {
              // Handle the server's response, if needed
              // For example, you can show a success message or trigger a file download
              console.log('Export successful!');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              // Handle errors, if any
              console.error('Export error:', error);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

while my /export endpoint which is used in the ajax request is :

```py
@views.route('/export', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def export():
    selected_rows = request.get_json()  # Get the selected rows' data from the request

    # Create a DataFrame from the selected rows' data
    df = pd.DataFrame(selected_rows, columns=['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4',
                                              'header5', 'header6',
                                              'header7',
                                              'header8'])

    # Generate an Excel file from the DataFrame
    excel_file = io.BytesIO()
    df.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)
    excel_file.seek(0)  # Move the file pointer to the beginning of the file
    # Prepare the response headers
    headers = {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=selected_rows.xlsx',
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    }

    # Return the Excel file contents as the response
    return Response(excel_file, headers=headers)
```

Although i get a 200 response back from the server ('127.0.0.1 - - [24/May/2023 19:21:00] "POST /export HTTP/1.1" 200 -'), no excel file is being downloaded (exported) to the client. Why is that?

Comment: Too much code... too broad of a question

Comment: @VirajShah I am literally trying to be as insightful for my program as possible in order to be able to help you understand whats going on. If i didn't provide you the code, how could you possibly be able to help me?
The question on the other hand isn't even too broad, I simply ask what am i missing in my export implementation. Very specific.

Comment: That's why you included all that irrelevant HTML code?

Comment: @VirajShah it happens very often for users to ask for the whole html code in order to run it themselves before writing a solution. That is why i included it. Now if you don't want to help me that's alright, you can just skip this question. I don't understand why take your time to judge me instead of providing any kind of help, especially when you can see this is my first time asking a question...

Comment: Because I'm moderating the site and StackOverflow literally **gave me this post** to review. So I provided my feedback, and you're arguing with me about it. I know a little something about content quality on this site. StackOverflow's guide requires a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I was giving you an opportunity to edit the post to comply with SOs rules so that I didn't have to delete it.

Comment: @VirajShah but if i modify it i feel like it will be incomplete. I just tried to provide as much info regarding the problem as i could. I guess i will cut only the part of the html code where the script regarding excel export lies. Tell me if it looks better...

Comment: are you able to print the data frame in the console and/or the browser console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got rid of the /export endpoint and fixed the issue with solely javascript code. For anyone interested, this is the code i used :

```js
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function getSelectedRows() {
        const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".row-checkbox");
        const selectedRows = [];
    
        checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
          if (checkbox.checked) {
            const row = checkbox.closest("tr");
            selectedRows.push(row);
          }
        });
    
        return selectedRows;
      }
    
      function exportReportToExcel() {
        const selectedRows = getSelectedRows();
    
        if (selectedRows.length === 0) {
          alert("No rows selected. Please select at least one row.");
          return;
        }
    
        const table = document.createElement("table");
        const tableBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    
        selectedRows.forEach(function (row) {
          tableBody.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true));
        });
    
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
    
        const wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(table, { sheet: "Sheet 1" });
        XLSX.writeFile(wb, "file.xlsx");
      }
    </script>
```